# USB 2.0 full speed audio class max sampling frequency?

Tags: audio, adc, usb-device

what is the maximum achivable sampling frequency when using USB 2.0 **full** speed isochronous audio transfer and **stereo 24bit** format (recording only) ?

**when no compression is used !**

Comment: What makes you think the sampling rate of the audio is in any way related to (or limited by) the speed of USB. Suppose my audio ADC is 24bit at 1 GHz sample rate. But I somehow **compress** (without losing information) the datastream such that it can easily pass over USB 2.0 full speed.

Comment: I'm interested in cases when no compression is used.

Answer (score 3):

USB2.0 full speed is the same as USB1.1 full speed.

USB1.1 frames have a length of 1ms, and isochronous transfers may put up to 1023 bytes into a frame. This gives you roughly **170 stereo 24bit samples per frame** – a 170ksample/s rate.

Even the simplest compression techniques as transferring the difference to the previous value instead of the actual value or joint-stereo, followed by special encoding for small difference values may nearly double that rate.

Comment: *USB2.0 full speed is the same as USB1.1 full speed.* Good one! USB 2.0 at 480 Mbps (signalling rate) is called **high speed**.